# Is running speed determined by distance, coins or score?

Tags: temple-run, temple-run-2

As a strategic motive, I would like to speed up less, but I don't know how running velocity is calculated?

- Is it fixed to the meters run, so not much can be done about it?
- Or to coins, so I could collect less coins if my primary goal was to maximize distance or score?
- Or is the speed caused by your score, or perhaps something else altogether?

P.S. Found some helpful tips on how to temporarily slow down here: [Does anything slow down or reset running speed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105842/does-anything-slow-down-or-reset-running-speed)

Comment: To start with, add which game you refer to to the title and description!

Comment: @Andreas Uh, doesn't the tags already tell you that? In general we don't include the name of the game in the title of the question because the tags already do so.

Comment: I was under the impression that the deciding factor is *time*. So the longer you run, the faster you run, irrespective of your score.  This would increase the incentive to gather as much as can at all times. Never tested this though.

Comment: @Alex great point! has anyone tested it somehow, might this be the definitive answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Temple run series is like jetpack joyride, it is based on momentum. You collect speed over running and the most efficient way to lose it is to 'resurrect' by using gems or wings depending on which game you play.

Tripping, or collecting powerups, has nothing to do with your speed.

Comment: Thanks!!! The deciding factor can still be thought of as time, but time alive (while tripping does definitely slow you down transiently, which makes it easier to stay alive longer)

Answer (score 1):

In Temple Run 2, I have noticed consistently that when the random resurrection spin comes up with the with the speed boost, the running speed after the boost wears off is noticeably slower.  Many of my longest runs came about from happening to roll that boost a couple of times after deaths.

Comment: My initial suspension is that this is simply something you perceive to be the case because you were moving so quickly before and suddenly you're not moving as fast any longer. If you could cite some evidence, that'd be fantastic.

Comment: I thought of that as well and I'm pretty sure that it's genuine. I'll try to measure but that's not so easy to do.  It has been quite consistent for a while, now that it's been some months since the resurrection wheel has been around.